# IMPORTRANGE referring to a cell with link instead of link itself. And Range using cell value instead of sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to `IMPORTRANGE("http://page","Sheet!A11:F")`

Where the page is a link located in a cell on the current sheet, and the range is also in a cell on the current sheet.

For example:  `IMPORTRANGE("'C8'","'A1'!All:F")`  Something like that.

My overall goal is to be able to copy the current workbook, add a sheet, put a reference number in A1, then have the sheet automatically pull data (using an A1 vlookup from a master list) from the correct sheet in another workbook without having to manually relink eveyrthing.  Just want to put the unique ticker in A1.

The application is there is a 'Master Deal List' workbook.  Each row has a different deal with a unique 3 digit 'ticker' in Column A and the deal's sheet in another workbook link in column F.  This second workbook (Deals) with distribution data named with the same 3 digit ticker.  Finally each investor in each deal has a 3rd workbook which needs to pull distribution amounts from the right sheet in the Deals workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, answer is here:

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-sheet-names-in-importrange/

Answer:

```
IMPORTRANGE("http://page", A1&"!A11:ZZ")
```